# Create Multiarrays to display in datatable PDO,PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, pdo

hope your well.
I have a query that give me a result as below:

[image: Sql result]

I need this be a multi array to display it in a datatable
Like this:

```
Article, Products,  Supname,    Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4, Week5, Week6, and so on
1         Product 1  Supplier 1  0,27   0,6    0,36   0,58   0,78   0,32  and so on
```

I get all the result with PDO because we are using an SQL server, 
my code for creating the array is this:

```
$pos = 0;
$x = 0; 
$End = count($getAll);
$html = array();
$html2 = array();    

while ($x <= 53) { 
    if ($x == 0) {   
        $html[] = array('Articleno' => $getAll[$pos+1]["ArtNo"], 'Name' => ''.$getAll[$pos+1]["Product"], 'Supname' => $getAll[$pos+1]["Levnamn"]);
    } 

    $html2 = array('M'.$getAll[$pos]["Weekno"] => $getAll[$pos]["Qty"].' , '.$getAll[$pos]["Sold"]);

    $html = array_merge($html, $html2);
    $x++;
    $pos++;

    if ($x == 53){ 
        $x=0;
    }

    if ($pos==$End){
        $x=70;
    }    
}
```

The result is not even near, i have tried alot of different solutions but this is the closest one.
Im missing the alla the week information for product2. This is can be filled with up to 150 products.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your array like this:

```php
$stm = $pdo->query('your SQL query');
$output = [];
while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $ident = $row['Articleno'].';'.$row['Product'].';'.$row['Supname'];
  $ref = &$output[$ident];
  if(!is_array($ref))
  {
    $ref['Article'] = $row['Articleno'];
    $ref['Product'] = $row['Product'];
    $ref['Supname'] = $row['Supname'];
    $ref['Week1'] = [0,0];
    $ref['Week2'] = [0,0];
    $ref['Week3'] = [0,0];
    $ref['Week4'] = [0,0];
    $ref['Week5'] = [0,0];
    $ref['Week6'] = [0,0];
  }
  $weekNo = $row['Weekno'];
  $ref['Week'.$weekNo] = [$row['Qty'], $row['Sold']];
}
echo json_encode(array_values($output));
```

Comment: Great solution, Big thx!